# How bad are dusters on PCBs?

Tags: pcb, static, cleaning

There are 3 types of dusters that I know of:

1. [Microfibre](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00940DV6W)
2. [Electrostatic](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B003S9FWFS)
3. [Vehicular](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dacia_Duster)

AFAIK, the microfibre variant relies more on contact with dust than on electrostatic attraction, unlike the electrostatic variant. Still, I think there is plenty of *potential* for static buildup.

Which brings me to some of the exposed PCBs I have lying around, varying from a caseless desktop PC to various dev boards. What happens if you use a dust cleaner on them? On one hand, static is a known enemy of electronics. On the other hand, PCBs have lots of metallic contacts and traces, which might help dissipate any static before it builds to IC-destroying levels.

I have a strong suspicion someone already did some experimental research on this, but I can't find any.

Comment: Real bad. Do not use. Metallic contacts do not dissipate ESD any more than the pipes in your house drain water away in a flood. Only your drain does that because your drain actually goes to the sewer. Everything else goes other places that you don't want flood water getting into.

Comment: LOL  @ the 'automotive' duster   ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My anecdotal experience is no fault using a vacuum with horsehair- like  brushes.  Current will be induced must be less than 5mA per pin.

All ESD buildup from friction with charged dust particles is called tribo-electric.

- in theory grabbing on to metal vacuum inlet and frame reduces voltage drop but raises current.  So discharge yourself 1st or use ESD strap.
- Let the ESD protection dual stage 10k + Schottky diodes do their job and keep clean. You may generate might be  more than 5mA but it will be shared by all protected triboelectric pins.  Use a tooth brush if you are a smoker with isoprop and dry throughly .
- I cleaned one guy’s PC (smoker with lots of fans and PC on floor and the dust looked like felt between pins,pads.!! Any humidity in dust can raise load >30pF per pin which is the design rating for rise time.
- if you poured Isoprop then you might need 24h warm air hair drier not too hot to get under IC otherwise , it might not boot up until you do.  Been there done that!
- I have also sucked up isoprop with central vacuum, which is **not advise for portable vacuum** as the fumes may ignite above LEL (lower explosive level) with a pop or flash in the motor.  battery vacuum is OK.

But that for my laptop with beer induced failure on keyboard. It worked and still works 10yr later.

The current is much more gentle than a 3kV 1nF zap from a long charged IO SCSI cable that can blow ESD protection diodes. (Production final test experience on a dry concrete dusty floor.)

Answer (score 2):

Nobody in their right mind would use those on PCBs.

You use [gas duster](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gas_duster) or isopropyl alcohol to rinse the board.

Comment: A gas duster velocity is not better for triboelectric charge creation than the velocity of a vacuum from the distance with same velocity except condensation to warm parts after the fact. -1

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 yes, it's cleaner than compressed air though, which often contains oil particles. With a vacuum the highest ESD risk is the plastic hose touching the board.

Comment: -1 from me, since it ignores the question. I'm not asking for a repeat of the mantras, but rather for their justification. And maybe some cool examples of things that got zapped.

Comment: I even zapped TTL in the old days when CMOS was unprotected and TTL still had contaminated silicon but you can easily find SEM photos of CMOs zapped it’s just that I have never zapped a PC with One hand on the frame at all times , vacuumed, brushed dry in 25% nominal RH, YMMV